# Equivalent characterizations of twice differentiable convex functions

Tags: optimization, convex-analysis

Let $f:C \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ be twice Frechet differentiable function on a convex open set $C \subseteq \mathbb{R}^{n}. $ The following statements are known to be equivalent:

1. $f$ is convex
2. $f(y) \geq f(x)+ \nabla f(x)^{T} (y-x)$ $\forall x,y \in C$
3. $\big<\nabla f(y)- \nabla f(x), y-x\big>\geq 0$
4. $Hf(x)$ is positive semidefinite at every $x\in C$

**Proof so far:** 
$(2) \implies (3)$ For all $x,y \in C$, we have

- $f(y) \geq f(x) +\nabla f(x)^{T} (y-x)$
- $f(x) \geq f(y) +\nabla f(y)^{T} (x-y)$
  Adding these two inequalities and cancelling like terms we have
- $0 \geq \nabla f(x)^{T} (y-x) +\nabla f(y)^{T} (x-y) \implies 0 \leq \big<\nabla f(y)- \nabla f(x), y-x\big>$

$(3) \implies (2)$
Let $x,y \in C$. By MVT there exists $0 < \lambda <1$ s.t.
$$ f(y)-f(x)=\nabla f(x_{\lambda})^{T}(y-x)$$ where $x_{\lambda}= \lambda y+(1-\lambda)x$. Then
$$0\leq \big[\nabla f(x_{\lambda})-\nabla f(x)\big]^{T} (x_{\lambda}-x)=\lambda \big[\nabla f(x_{\lambda})-\nabla f(x)\big]^{T} (y-x)= \lambda \big[ f(y)-f(x)-\nabla f(x)^{T}(y-x)\big]$$
$\implies f(y) \geq f(x)+ \nabla f(x)^{T} (y-x)$

$(4) \implies (3)$
$f(y)=f(x)+\nabla f(x)^{T} (y-x)+\frac{1}{2}(y-x)^{T}Hf(z_{1}) (y-x)$ and
$f(x)=f(y)+\nabla f(y)^{T} (x-y)+\frac{1}{2}(x-y)^{T}Hf(z_{2}) (x-y)$
Since $Hf(x)$ is positive semidefnite for all $x \in C$
So

- $f(y) \geq f(x)+ \nabla f(x)^{T} (y-x)$
- $f(x) \geq f(y)+ \nabla f(y)^{T} (x-y)$
  Then
  $\big<\nabla f(y)- \nabla f(x), y-x\big>\geq 0$

---

How to prove $(3)\implies (4)$?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Following the hint (the definition of gradient):

> Remember that $\nabla f(x+t h) - \nabla f(x) = Hf (x) t h + o(|t|)$ -- [user251257](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1461790/convex-functions-equivalent-statements#comment2977911_1461790)

Take the inner product of both sides with $th$: 
$$\langle \nabla f(x+t h) - \nabla f(x), th\rangle = t^2 h^THf (x)h   + o(|t|^2)$$
If $h^THf (x)h<0$, then the right hand side is negative for sufficiently small $t$, a contradiction.